# Nonsymmetric monoidal product on $[\mathbb N,\mathbf{Sets}]$

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathbf P$ be the category with objects the natural numbers and $\hom(m,n)=Sym(n)$ if $n=m$, and the empty set otherwise. It is symmetric monoidal wrt the sum of natural numbers, and has $0$ as a unit object.

Following the lines of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290833/associativity-of-day-convolution), I can endow $[\mathbf{P},\mathcal V]$, for any [Bénabou cosmos](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cosmos) $\cal V$, with a monoidal structure, defining 
$$
F_1\star\dots\star F_m = \int^{n_1,\dots, n_m}\mathbf{P}(n_1+\dots+n_m,-)\otimes_{\cal V}F_1n_1\otimes_{\cal V}\dots\otimes_{\cal V}F_mn_m
$$
Now I can define $F^{\star n}$ to be the $n$-fold convoluted product of $F$ with itself, and I can endow $[\mathbf{P},\mathcal V]$ with *another* (nonsymmetric) monoidal structure, define
$$
T\diamond S := \int^m T(m)\otimes_{\cal V} S^{\star m}
$$
My problem is to show the following identity: for any $F\in [\mathbf P,\mathcal V ]$, one has
$$
(\heartsuit)\qquad F^{\star n}\cong \mathbf{P}(n,-)\diamond F = \int^m\mathbf{P}(n,m)\otimes_{\cal V}F^{\star m}.
$$
Is it true? And if it is, how can I show it?

> Note: I tried to keep my question self-contained to help anybody understand my request; if it seems to you that I'm implying the real origin of the problem, I'm trying to prove Lemma 3.1 [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/13/tr13.pdf), and I'ms tuck in the row tagged with "by Yoneda".  As far as I can understand, the author is exploiting the identitiy $(\heartsuit)$ to conclude his proof.

Comment: It certainly doesn't work for arbitrary $\mathcal{V}$. At least it should be cocomplete, perhaps even a cosmos.

Comment: Woops, thanks for pointing it out. Yes, it has to be a cosmos (this is one of the initial remarks n Kelly's paper).

Comment: nlab says: "There are a number of different, inequivalent, definitions of “cosmos” in the literature." Which are you using?

Comment: I'm callng a 'cosmos' a complete and cocomplete closed symmetric monoidal category.

Comment: @tetrapharmakon, your $(\heartsuit)$ is *exactly* an instance of the Yoneda lemma (under assumption, that we know that $F^*$ is actually a functor --- which may be only non-trivial thing here).

Comment: I'm not able to see why...

Comment: Does it depend on the fact that $(n,F)\mapsto F^{\star n}$ is a *bi*functor $\mathbf{P}^{op}\times [\mathbf P,\mathcal V]\to [\mathbf P,\mathcal V]$?

Comment: @tetrapharmakon, the Yoneda lemma says that for any functor $K \colon \mathbb{P}^{op} \rightarrow \mathbb{V}$ there is a natural isomorphism: $K(A) \approx \int^C \hom(A, C) \otimes K(C)$. If you know that $F^*$ is a functor $n \mapsto F^{*n}$ from $\mathbb{P}^{op}$ to $\mathbb{V}$, then $F^{*n} \approx \int^m \hom(n, m) \otimes F^{*m}$ is an instance of the Yoneda lemma.